# Where do I set dovecot protocols

Tags: ubuntu, dovecot

I have /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf and then a lot of config files under /etc/dovecot/conf.d directory Which file should I edit to set protocols because in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf there's no protocol directive that isn't uncommented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the middle of the `/etc/dovecot/dovcot.conf` there should be a section as follows:

```
# Enable installed protocols
!include_try /usr/share/dovecot/protocols.d/*.protocol
```

This builds up the `protocols` list object by having each file append the required protocol to the end of the list e.g. `/usr/share/dovecot/protocols.d/imapd.protocol` contains the following:

```
protocols = $protocols imap
```

Comment: My directory /usr/share/dovecot/protocols.d is empty, maybe because I purged and reinstalled dovecot

Comment: Have you also installed the `dovecot-imapd` package?

Comment: Thanks Having done that eliminated the error Next error is mail_location issue On my server mail is located under /var/mail/<username> so what should I set mail_location to?

Comment: New Problem -> New Question (also feel free to upvote/accept this answer if it helped)